# java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:577). Fail to ParseInt

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error when I trying to parseInt inside dataSnapshot and after I comment the parseInt, it comes with error with partDouble, this error occurs when I added dataSnapshot.exist() in my if else statement:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:577)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
```

The complete code:

```
 final String key = ds.push().getKey();
                    ds.orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
                                SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
                                String month = (String) dataSnapshot.child("month").getValue();
                                int tcount = Integer
                                        .parseInt((String) dataSnapshot.child("trans").getValue()) + 1;
                                double value = Double
                                        .parseDouble((String) dataSnapshot.child("amt").getValue());
                                double mvalue = Double
                                        .parseDouble((String) dataSnapshot.child("monthamt").getValue());
                                value = roundOff(value);
                                mvalue = roundOff(mvalue);
                                if (fm.format(c.getTime()).equals(month)) {
                                    ds.child("monthamt").setValue(roundOff(mvalue + amt) + "");
                                } else {
                                    ds.child("month").setValue(fm.format(c.getTime()));
                                    ds.child("monthamt").setValue(amt + "");
                                }

                                dt.child("Bill").child(k).child("gtranid").setValue(tcount + "");
                                ds.child("trans").setValue(tcount + "");
                            } else {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
                                SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
                                ds.child(key).child("date").setValue(format.format(c.getTime()));
                                ds.child(key).child("amt").setValue(amt + "");
                                ds.child(key).child("month").setValue(fm.format(c.getTime()));
                                ds.child(key).child("monthamt").setValue(amt + "");
                                ds.child(key).child("trans").setValue("1");

                                dt.child("Bill").child(k).child("gtranid").setValue("1");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
```

My Firebase database:
[Firebase Summary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odWcO.png)

Comment: You can't parse a `null` value. Most likely the `dataSnapshot.child("trans").getValue()` is returning null, find out why.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it by changing the parseInt and parseDouble value into valueOf

```
double value = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("amt").getValue()));
```